# Is there a way to only show a field if specified using django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Is there a way to show a field only if its specified in the `?field=X` param? If I try this:

```
class TopLevelJobSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children_job_statuses = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = TopLevelJob # This inherits from Job, which has id, name
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

I get `AssertionError: The field 'children_job_statuses' was declared on serializer TopLevelJobSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.`

The `children_job_statuses` is a property that takes a while to load. I only want to call this explicitly by calling `/api/top_level_job/?fields=children_job_statuses`

How can I do this? Do I need a whole new serializer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061718/django-rest-framework-hide-specific-fields-in-list-display - read the part related to `get_fields` method

Comment: @dmitryro are you referring to Sergei's answer? If so, would I then pop off the field I didn't want unless it was explicitly specified?

Comment: In the method you can check if the condition holds and pop it for this viewset rendering only, checking the condition will allow you to limit in which case to pop.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but how can I check if the condition holds? `request.parser_context.get('kwargs')` is a blank dictionary even if I pass `fields= children_job_statuses`

Comment: This is a GET request, and you can run `dir(requests)` or `print(dir(requests))` to see where the parameter is located. It's in requests object.

Comment: FYI this is in the drf docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#example

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
    fields = super().get_fields(*args, **kwargs)
    request = self.context.get('request')
    if request is None or not 'fields' in request.query_params or 'children_job_statuses' not in \
            request.query_params['fields']:
        fields.pop('children_job_statuses', None)

    return fields
```